# Multiple-parties signature schemes

Tags: signature

please let me know if there's any digital signature scheme for the following problem. Thanks in advance!

- I want to have a token that's somehow signed (or granted) by multiple
  3rd parties for a certain document. The token then can be used to
  access resources managed by the parties.
- 3rd parties just need to use their private keys to validate the token

I find the Wiki article about [Multisignature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisignature), but really I don't know how to apply it into my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the token as a random number. Have each of the parties sign the token independently. Each will provide one signature on the token. Concatenate all the signatures into a big string. That string can then be sent when resources are requested. Each party can verify that its own signature exists in the string.

Comment: So I think we should have a map between public keys and associated signatures in the tokens, right? If there are many parties, wow, the tokens will be really really big strings.

Comment: If you don't mind the third parties keeping state, then during a request for resources the requester can send the token and the third party can store the token persistently. Then when the resource needs to be consumed, the token is transmitted again and the provider checks to see if the resources were previously requested. This solves the large token issue.